# Loop through array that is dynamic in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this array declared in my `.ts` file

```
  opt_1=[];
  opt_2=[];
  opt_3=[];
  opt_4=[];
```

and in `.html component` there is an outer loop

```
 <span *ngFor="let list of current_lists[0]; let i = index">
     <div *ngFor="let item of opt_{{i}}">{{ item }}</div>
 <span>
```

this `opt_{{i}}` i want to make it dynamic so that i can access all the elements of array

```
<div *ngFor="let item of opt_{{i}}">{{ item }}</div>
```

but getting syntax related errors.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Have you considered doing this in your component `.ts` file and only returning just what you need to the `.html`.

Comment: @fortunee in my component I want this loop to run `current_lists[0]` is already populated with data from `ts` file, `opt_1, opt_2 ...`is filled on button click, second loop is to print these arrays till `ith` index

Answer (score 0):

use bracket notation to access properties like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of this['opt_'+i]">{{item}}</div>
```